# Derivative of a natural log to the power.

Tags: calculus

I'm reviewing for my calc final, and I have this question:

$$f(x) = (\ln x)^{x^2}$$

What I did was just take the derivative of the power, which is $2x$, then the derivative of lnx and got:

$$\frac{2x}{x}$$

However, the correct answer is:

$$(\ln x)^{x^2} (2x \ln \ln x + x^2\frac{1}{\ln x}\frac{1}{x})$$

Can anyone explain how to get this answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have formulas of the form $$h=f^g$$

what you want to do is differentiate the much easier $\log h=g\log f$ and get what $\frac {h'}h$ is. Then multiply by $h$, and you're done.

*Example* $f(x)=x^x$. Then $\log f=x\log x$ so that upon differentiation $\frac{f'}{f}=1+\log x$, thus

$$f'=x^x(1+\log x)$$

**ADD** More correctly, you have that $$f(x)=(\log x)^{x^2}=e^{\log [(\log x)^{x^2}]}$$

This in turn is $$f(x)=e^{x^2\log\log x}$$

Now use the chain rule with $h(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=x^2\log\log x$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=(\ln x)^{x^2}=e^{x^2\ln\ln x}$$
let $g(x)=x^2\ln\ln(x)$
then $g(x)'=2x\ln \ln(x)+\dfrac{x^2}{x\ln x}$

so $f(x)'=e^{x^2\ln \ln x}\cdot(2x\ln \ln(x)+\dfrac{x^2}{x\ln x}=(\ln x)^{x^2}\cdot2x\ln \ln(x)+\dfrac{x^2}{x\ln x}$

Hope I can help you.

Comment: Please, use `\ln` to get $\ln$ instead of $ln$.